# How to display a blob with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, blob

I got a script which takes several images from my MySQL database, which are stored as blobs. This script is accessed from a JavaScript / Ajax request.

So for now i display the blob in a div. But how can i convert the blob to an image in JavaScript?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jan_Miksovsky/yy7Zs/

Comment: You have to serve it from the server, not send it with ajax, or if you just have to send it with ajax, use `base64_encode` first so it's valid Base64 when it's received.

Answer (score 3):

**First,** you could expose the image data as resources on the server-side then instantiate an image node in your client-side with the `src` set the appropriate URL.

```
<img src="mydomain/images/my-resource.png" />
```

The resource `mydomain/images/my-resource.png` does not need to be a static resource on the server; the URL just needs to return the image data in an HTTP response.

**Second,** if you have the blob in base64 on the client-side already, use a `data-url`. Format ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)):

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
```

Example ([from Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

If you actually have raw binary data on the client-side then the [btoa function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) may be of use when constructing said `data-url`.

**Finally,** you could also use the HTML5 File API, performing an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-responsetype), configured with a responseType of either `'blob'`, or `'arraybuffer'`. You can then instantiate [an in-memory URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) for the object, and assign this to the `src` of an `Image` DOM node.